# How to publish .net core project to smarterasp.net from vscode?

Tags: asp.net-core, server

I need to publish .net core project to smarterasp.net server. I use visual studio code. How can I deploy my project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've run into bugs with Web Deploy, so I use a Folder (aka 'File') deploy to a local folder and then FTP the content of that folder to the root website folder at SmarterASP.NET.  The main trick is that when you set up your publishing profile, you must change to 'self contained' and target x86.  If you leave the default settings, your site won't work.  I'm referring to Core 3 here....

Answer (score 1):

since I don't know the smarterasp.net provider, but unless you have a free hosting plan, smarterasp.net declares that ASP.NET Core 3.x is already installed for which you only need to build your project and inserting it in the root of your IIS site without installing the core framework on the server would not work.
Good luck.

Comment: At SmarterASP.NET, regardless of what they advertise, you MUST make your deployment self-contained and target x86.  At other providers, who actually DO completely support Core 3+ (such as InterServer.net), you can leave the publishing profile settings at their defaults and as you say, just deposit your files in your application root ... and voila!  It works.  I posted here specifically for SmarterASP.Net because they do NOT support Core 3+ deployments with default settings.  That's a config issue on their side.  After their recent ransomware attack, they are very busy and are not keeping up.